# PySide QWidget immediate update

Tags: python, qt, pyside

In my application, I have a call to an external module which spawns some threads, does some stuff, then returns a value. I'm trying to get a QMessageBox to show *before* and a QLabel to update *after* this is complete, but I'm stumped. The code goes something like this (called from QObject.connect on a button):

```
def _process(self):
  self._message_box.show()

  for i in range(3):
     rv = external_module_function_with_threads() // blocking function call
     label = getattr(self, "label%d" % (i + 1))
     label.setText(rv)
```

When I click the button and the function is called, the message box only shows after the loop completes. The labels only update after the loop completes as well. I tried calling label.repaint() in the loop, but all that seems to do is make the message box show up earlier (but with no text in it).

I know I'm not violating the "GUI operations from outside the main thread" rule (...right?), so is there a way to force an update?

Answer (score 1):

For your message box use `self._message_box.exec_()`.  From my understanding of your question, I think this will do what you want.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *

import sys
import time


class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        button = QPushButton("Press me")
        self.label = QLabel("Run #")

        map(layout.addWidget, [button, self.label])
        button.pressed.connect(self.buttonPressed)

        self.messageBox = QMessageBox()

    def buttonPressed(self):
        self.messageBox.exec_()
        Thread().run(self.label)


class Thread(QThread):

    def run(self, label):
        for x in range(5):
            self.updateLabel(label)
            app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(.5)

    def updateLabel(self, label):
        try:
            number = int(label.text().split(" ")[-1])
            number += 1
        except ValueError:
            number = 0
        label.setText("Run %i" % number)


app = QApplication([])
main = Main()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```